# Finding a Hamiltonian cycle in a graph if we are guaranteed that there are not many of them in the graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-algorithms, hamiltonian-paths

Problem: Given an undirected simple graph $G=(V,E)$ on $n$ vertices, such that there are not more than $c^n$ ($c<2$) Hamiltonian cycles in $G$, find a Hamiltonian Cycle in $G$ if there exists one.

I remember seeing a paper (by Björklund if I remember correctly) that gives an algorithm for this problem. I am having trouble relocating that paper. Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: Presumably there is a [parsimonious reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsimonious_reduction) from [UNAMBIGUOUS-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Extensions_of_SAT) to Hamiltonian Cycle, so that the Hamiltonian Cycle problem restricted to graphs with at most one Hamiltonian Cycle is essentially NP-hard (NP-hard under randomized reductions)...  So what kind of algorithm are you hoping for?

Comment: @NealYoung, I am looking for an exact exponential time algorithm for the problem. Thanks for pointing out the hardness.